# Problem in sending mail with attachement

Tags: 7, emails, files

I'm coding a small module allowing to send mail to new users with an attachement file as pdf. This pdf include all subscription details of the user.

I generated the pdf file using FPDF and I put it (temporary) in DRUPAL_ROOT and I used two ways to send the mail:

1) Using the `hook_mail_alter`:

```
function aos_user_pdf_mail_alter(&$message) {  
  if($message['id']=='user_register_pending_approval') {  
    $attachment = array(  
     'filecontent' => file_get_contents(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . 'yourfilename.pdf'),  
     'filename' => 'yourfilename.pdf',  
     'filemime' => 'application/pdf'  
    );  
    $message['params']['attachments'][] = $attachment;  
  }  
}
```

2) Or creating a custom function:

```
function aos_user_pdf_send_mail ($mail, $uid) {  
  $user = user_load($uid);  
  $to = $mail;//gets the current user's mail address  
  $from = variable_get('site_mail', ''); //admin's mail address  
  $body = 'This is a test mail';  
  $subject = 'Your pdf';  
  $attachment = array(  
    'filecontent' => file_get_contents(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . 'yourfilename.pdf'),  
    'filename' => 'FILE',  
    'filemime' => 'application/pdf',   
  );  
  $message = drupal_mail('aos_user_pdf', 'message_key', $to,
    user_preferred_language($user),
    array(
      'body' => $body,
      'subject' => $subject,
      'attachment' => $attachment),
      $from,
      TRUE
    );  
}
```

Unfortunately the mail is sent, but without the attachement, Please can you show me where's my mistake or an alternative way to do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sending mail with attachment you should use [Mail System](https://drupal.org/project/mailsystem) and [Mime Mail](https://drupal.org/project/mimemail) module
Attachment functionality is built into the Mime Mail module.

After that you must set up drupal_mail() to use mime mail as the mail system interface. This is where the mail system module comes into play. The module is pretty straightforward, and lets you set a different mail system per module. There is a straightforward configuration at admin/config/system/mailsystem where you create a new setting for your module, and select mime mail as the mail system.

Assing anttatcment in variable

```
$message['params']['attachments']
```

After that you will be able to send mail with attachment.

For more information visit [here](http://rapiddg.com/blog-post/drupal-7-html-e-mail-pdf-attachments)

Comment: Thank you very much, i installed the mime mail module and the above functions worked finely without any modification.